# How can I achieve this type of view used in Wunderlist iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

How can I create the types of view that slide up from the bottom of the screen as pictured below? Is this a built-in view type or something custom?

The screen shots are from **Wunderlist** and **The Hit List**  iOS apps respectively.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a look at **The Hit List** there. Seems like they're just animating a view up from the bottom.

I'd go about this by creating a `UIView`, let's call it `slidingView`. You can do it in your existing storyboard or create a new .xib file for it. Then, when you call your `viewDidLoad` for the view controller that this `slidingView` will be contained in, move the `slidingView` view off screen and animate it in whenever you want.

### Example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private struct Constants {

        static let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 0.3
        static let marginFromTop: CGFloat = 32.0

    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var slidingView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        moveSlidingViewOffScreen()
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.animationDuration) {
            self.slidingView.frame.origin.y = Constants.marginFromTop
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private functions

    private func setupSlidingViewOffScreen() {
        slidingView.frame.origin.y = view.frame.height
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this to work. However, it seems to be transparent for some reason.

Comment: The `sllidingView` that you are animating in is transparent? How did you set it up? Storyboard or code?

Comment: I had the layering wrong and got it working. :) Thanks for the reply!